# Why my <signal.h> define __sig_atomic_t to int instead of volatile int

Tags: c, signals

I am reading "Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective", in chapter 8, it says sig_atomic can be use to be the type for flag which can be used in signal handler. But when I trace my header file, it is defined as int without volatile, isn't it means there is a possibility that when main modify the flag, it may use 'write back' instead of 'write through', which might be incorrect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [`sig_atomic_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/sig_atomic_t) should in practice always be qualified with `volatile` (at least for variables set inside signal handlers). It is not (formally) related to C11 [atomic types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic) (even if the name could be confusing). But `sig_atomic_t` should in practice be some integral type which can be written to or read from memory in a single [machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code) instruction (and you need to qualify it as `volatile` to make that happen as needed, and instruct the compiler to not cache it in some register etc...).

For Linux, see also [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and most importantly [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html).

Notice that the C11 standard does not tell a lot about [signals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/signal) (check by reading [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), notably §7.14). In practice, you probably need some [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) support for them. See also POSIX [signal concepts](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04).

Read also [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)

Comment: Then is there any `atomic` happening?

Comment: here, atomic just refers to read **or** write access, `sig_atomic_t` must be a type that can be read or written with a single instruction (but **not** something like test AND modify with just one instruction)